# Embeding JSX as a string variable into other JSX code in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have JSX code but it is within a string. trying to inject that code inside other JSX inside a React Component and having trouble...

I am using **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** however the JSX is being treated as HTML somehow. I have the className = "test" in JSX format... So, when rendered it has HTML class of test (which is red background)

## **React component trying to inject a JSX string into other JSX code**

```
  createMarkup(){  
    var htmlString = '<div className="test">TESTING</div>';
    return {__html : htmlString}

  }

  render() {
     return (
        <div id="pageContent" className="container" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()}></div>
      );   
  }
```

It is inserting the string variable, but when you inspect it, the output is this: (you can see the outter div's className is now class, however the string that was inserted still is seen as className

## **Browser Inspector looking at the rendered code**

```
<div id="pageContent" class="container"><div classname="test">TESTING</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So maybe I'm a year or two late but, I suspect that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` expects not a JSX string but instead, a HTML String.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  createMarkup() {
    var htmlString = '<div class="test">TESTING</div>'; // class instead of className
    return { __html: htmlString };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id="pageContent"
        className="container"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()}
      />
    );
  }
}


let main = document.getElementById("main");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, main);

console.log("The innerHTML of `#main` is:")
console.log(main.innerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

## `innerJSX` instead of `innerHTML`

And if you absolutely have to set `innerJSX` which you appear not to, you can do so using `babel`, but different ways depending on whether you're using `node` or `browser` js.

**NodeJS**: You'll need `@babel/core` and `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` for this and React with webpack will support this.

```
let parseJSX = (function() {
  let babel = require("@babel/core");
  return function(str) {
    let code = babel.transformSync(str, {
      plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"]
    }).code;
    return eval(code);
  }
})()
```

**Browser**: This refers to in-browser only ReactJS. You'll also need babel for this.

```
// Assuming babel is already loaded.
function parseJSX(str) {
  return eval(
    Babel.transform(str, 
      {
        presets: [],
        plugins: ["transform-react-jsx"]
      }
    ).code
  )
}
```

## Testing

**Browser**

```js
// Browser Version (Babel is loaded)
function parseJSX(str) {
  return eval(
    Babel.transform(str, 
      {
        presets: [],
        plugins: ["transform-react-jsx"]
      }
    ).code
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  createMarkup() {
    var jsxString = '<div className="test">TESTING</div>'; // className as in JSX
    return parseJSX(jsxString);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id="pageContent"
        className="container"
      >
      {this.createMarkup()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


let main = document.getElementById("main");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, main);

console.log("The innerHTML of `#main` is:")
console.log(main.innerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the content passed through `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is expected to an HTML and its not parsed by React and hence the `className` attribute isn't parsed to `class`, The content must follow the HTML convention of adding attributes must look like

```
createMarkup(){  
    var htmlString = '<div class="test">TESTING</div>';
    return {__html : htmlString}

  }

  render() {
     return (
        <div id="pageContent" className="container" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()}></div>
      );   
  }
```

However you could rather write it like

```
  createMarkup(){  
    return <div className="test">TESTING</div>
  }

  render() {
     return (
        <div id="pageContent" className="container">{this.createMarkup()}</div>
      );   
  }
```

Comment: How would i go about passing in JSX then? I need it to be JSX (there will be cases where there is components in that string)

Comment: You would rather render them as children of div instead of using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: but this doesn't solve this string issue. I would still be passing in the Children as Strings and React wouldn't parse the Strings as JSX

Comment: Why would you want to pass the children as strings

Comment: @user10059818  You cannot have JSX components as strings because JSX is not a string. JSX is just sugar for function calls which need context. aka `<div />` is really `React.createElement('div')` it only looks like html but the precompiler rewrites your jsx into nested function calls

Comment: so there is no possible way to turn the string into JSX

Comment: It's possible, but you would need to literally parse the string and turn the parsed string into function calls, which can be difficult depending on what you're trying to do. it's more common to store the data structure representing what you want to display and recreate it, instead of storing it as a string.

Comment: The real question is *why* is your JSX represented as a string?